# How to add a location data to Quickblox dialog?

Tags: android, quickblox

I would like to store a location type with a chat so I could search dialogues based on a location, so I created a Custom Object called *MyDialog* using the Quickblox Admin Panel. This custom object has only one field called **location** of type **Location**.

I tried two approaches to save the location data with the dialog, but both gave me problems:

**Approach 1: Store a Double[]**

```
    Double myLocation[] = {locationManager.getLastLocation().getLatitude()
            locationManager.getLastLocation().getLongitude()};

    Map<String,String> customParameters = new HashMap<>();
    customParameters.put("data[class_name]","MyDialog");
    customParameters.put("data[location]", Arrays.toString(myLocation));

    final QBDialog qbDialog = new QBDialog();
    qbDialog.setName("Test");
    qbDialog.setType(QBDialogType.GROUP);
    qbDialog.setData(customParameters);
```

**Problem 1**

The problem with this approach is that the created dialog always have **latitude '0'**. Here are the dialog creation response:

```
{
    "_id":"56448a1aa28f9ad7af000164",
    "created_at":"2015-11-12T12:46:18Z",
    "data":{"_qb_location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0,-42.6159729]},"class_name":"MyDialog"}, (...) }
```

**Approach 2: Store a QBLocation**

```
QBLocation qbLocation = new QBLocation(locationManager.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),
            locationManager.getLastLocation().getLongitude());

Map<String,String> customParameters = new HashMap<>();
customParameters.put("data[class_name]","MyDialog");
customParameters.put("data[location]", qbLocation.toString());

final QBDialog qbDialog = new QBDialog();
qbDialog.setName("Test");
qbDialog.setType(QBDialogType.GROUP);
qbDialog.setData(customParameters);
```

**Problem 2**

The problem with this approach is that the created dialog always have **coordinates : [0,0]**. Here are the dialog creation response:

```
{
    "_id":"56448a1aa28f9ad7af000164",
    "created_at":"2015-11-12T12:46:18Z",
    "data":{"_qb_location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0,0]},"class_name":"MyDialog"}, (...) }
```

To retrieve the nearby dialogues I have this code

```
Double[] myLocation = {locationManager.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),
            locationManager.getLastLocation().getLongitude()};

    final QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
    requestBuilder.setPagesLimit(5);
    requestBuilder.near("data[location]",myLocation,NEARBY_ROOMS_DISTANCE);

    QBChatService.getChatDialogs(QBDialogType.GROUP, requestBuilder,
            new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBDialog>>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final ArrayList<QBDialog> dialogs, Bundle args) {

                    if(dialogs.size()!=0) {

                        roomsEvents.setEvent(RoomsEvents.ROOM_RETRIEVED);
                        roomsEvents.setQbDialog(dialogs.get(0));
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(roomsEvents);

                    }else{

                        roomsEvents.setEvent(RoomsEvents.NO_ROOMS_NEARBY);
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(roomsEvents);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {

                     roomsEvents.setEvent(RoomsEvents.RETRIEVE_ROOM_ERROR);
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(roomsEvents);

                }

            });
    }
```

My **Location Manager**:

```
public class LocationManagement implements LocationManager {

private Context mContext;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Inject
public LocationManagement(Context mContext){

    this.mContext = mContext;

    startGooglePlayServices();
}

private void startLocationUpdates(){

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(10000)
            .setFastestInterval(5000)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;

    shareOwnLocation(mLastLocation);
}

@Override
public void shareOwnLocation(Location location) {

    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();


    QBLocation qbLocation = new QBLocation(lat, lng);
    QBLocations.createLocation(qbLocation, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBLocation>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBLocation qbLocation, Bundle bundle) {

            LocationEvents locationEvent = new LocationEvents();
            locationEvent.setEvent(LocationEvents.LOCATION_SHARED);

            EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();
            eventBus.post(locationEvent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> list) {

            // TODO
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public float distanceToMyLocation(Location destiny) {

    return mLastLocation.distanceTo(destiny);
}

@Override
public Location buildLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

    Location mLocation = new Location("");
    mLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    mLocation.setLongitude(longitude);

    return mLocation;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        shareOwnLocation(mLastLocation);

    }else{

       startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void startGooglePlayServices() {

    this.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void disconnectToGoogleApi() {

    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void connectToGoogleApi() {

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public Location getLastLocation() {

    return mLastLocation;
}
}
```

Whats the correct way to store a location type with a chat and still be able to retrieve the nearby rooms?

Comment: @MrsEd, I added the code that I'm using to retrieve the chats, it's just a callback that uses [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library to notify that the chats were retrieved. And, to be clear, I need help to associate a **Location** type with a **QBDialog**, because I was using those two approaches but they both store the location data incorrectly.

Comment: @MrsEd, I'm pretty sure that problem isn't with my location manager, because before I retrieve the chats, I store my current location at the Quickblox servers and it's stored with the correct latitude and longitude. But if you want it, take a look. I edited my code.

Comment: No problem @MrsEd ;-) . And thanks for the attention.

Comment: Can you post your logs of REST request? will analyse and get back with the recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma in between your doubles in myLocation:

```
Double myLocation[] = {locationManager.getLastLocation().getLatitude()
        locationManager.getLastLocation().getLongitude()};
```

To:

```
Double myLocation[] = {locationManager.getLastLocation().getLatitude(),
        locationManager.getLastLocation().getLongitude()};
```

From our extended discussion, I think the second attempt is failing due to using QBLocation, when you are looking for Location.

Another problem may be instead of:

```
Double myLocation[] = {locationManager.getLastLocation().getLatitude()
        locationManager.getLastLocation().getLongitude()};

Map<String,String> customParameters = new HashMap<>();
customParameters.put("data[class_name]","MyDialog");
customParameters.put("data[location]", Arrays.toString(myLocation));
```

`Arrays.toString(myLocation))` will include "[lat,long]"

The lat and long needs to be formatted as "lat,long"

```
String locationStr = locationManager.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+","+
        locationManager.getLastLocation().getLongitude();

Map<String,String> customParameters = new HashMap<>();
customParameters.put("data[class_name]","MyDialog");
customParameters.put("data[location]", locationStr);
```

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/29